# Twitter bot with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, twitter, bots

I am trying to make a twitter bot with selenium which will get the links of tweets and then reply them one by one. There are many [tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ovFudqFB0Q&t=691s). I am having many problems. First, only if i am logged out of my twitter account, the tweets are opening in a popup otherwise not. I don't know the reason. The class for heart button is 'HeartAnimation' when tweet is opening in a popup. And if i am logged in, i cannot get 'data-pemalink-path' for tweets. Now i cannot find the class of reply button. The class i am using is not working. It is throwing a NoSuchElement exeption. This is my code. Please tell me if i am doing something wrong.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
hashtag = 'pycon'
driver.get('https://twitter.com/search?q='+hashtag+'&src=typd')
time.sleep(3)
for i in range(1,3):
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
    time.sleep(30)
    tweets = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tweet')
    links = [elem.get_attribute('data-permalink-path') 
    for elem in tweets]
    time.sleep(3)
driver.get('https://twitter.com/login?prefetchTimestamp=1569146832519')
username_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-username-field.email-input.js-initial-focus')
username_field.send_keys('email')
time.sleep(0.5)
pass_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-password-field')
pass_field.send_keys('password')
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('submit.EdgeButton.EdgeButton--primary.EdgeButtom--medium').click()
time.sleep(3)
for link in links:
    driver.get('https://twitter.com' + link)
    time.sleep(7)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-1dbjc4n.r-18u37iz.r-1h0z5mdr-3qxfft.r-h4g966.r-rjfia').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    reply = driver.find_element_by_class_name('notranslate.public-DraftEditor-content')
    reply.send_keys('wow!')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-18t94o4.css-1dbjc4n.r-urgr8i.r-42olwf.r-sdzlij.r-1phboty.r-rs99b7.r-1w2pmg.r-1n0xq6e.r-1vuscfd.r-1dhvaqw.r-1fneopy.r-o7ynqc.r-6416eg.r-lrvibr').click()
    time.sleep(8)
```

Comment: Scraping or automating the website is against the Twitter Terms of Service. You should use the official Twitter API. Try a library like tweepy.

Comment: Dear Andy well I don't see he was interested in Twitter user policy. He wanted know how to automatize his twitter account. You are not responsible for upholding twitter rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [twpy](https://github.com/0x0ptim0us/twpy) lib, high level, no login no api required,
I'm author of twpy lib

Answer (score -2):

Without using selenium, 
There is also a way to use twitter-scraper.
https://qiita.com/katafuchix/items/6fd6b15685fe48f69e89